# Dropzone.js not showing in vue-js-modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, dropzone.js

In a project, I am using the vue-js-modal plugin by euvl and dropzone.js for multiple file uploads.

I know want to combine both libraries and let the user open a modal and upload files. Unfortunately, it looks like the dropzone.js library is not initialized properly, the modal pops up, but I can't upload photos through the dropzone container.

Unfortunately, I don't get an error on the console, but the file upload window doesn't open and drag and drop of files is also not possible.

This is my vue component file:

```
<template>
<modal name="upload-files-modal" classses="p-4 bg-card rounded-lg" height="auto">
        <div class="card mt-3">
        <h3 class="font-normal text-xl py-4 -ml-5 mb-3 border-l-4 border-blue-light pl-4">
           Upload some pictures
        </h3>
            <form id="newForm" method="POST" action="" class="dropzone" >
            </form>
        </div>
</modal>
</template>

<script>
import Dropzone from 'dropzone'
import 'dropzone/dist/dropzone.css'

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
Dropzone.options.newForm = {
        paramName: 'photo',
        maxFilesize: 3,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png .bmp',
        init: function () {
        // Set up any event handlers
        this.on('queuecomplete', function (file) {
                location.reload();
        });
    }
}

export default {
    props: ['uploadurl']
}
</script>
```

This is how I use the vue component in my laravel blade file:

```
<upload-files-modal uploadurl="{{ $project->path() . '/photos' }}" ></upload-files-modal>

<a href="" @click.prevent=$modal.show('upload-files-modal')>Upload Photo</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should initialize `Dropzone` after modal opens up.

**Example**

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

const VModal = window["vue-js-modal"].default;

Vue.use(VModal)

const dropForm = Vue.component('drop-form', {

  template: `<div class="content">
  <modal name="modal" @opened="afterOpen">
    <div ref="dropZoneRef" class="dropzone"></div>
  </modal>
  <button @click="showModal()">Upload files</button></div>`,
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$modal.show('modal')
    },
    afterOpen() {
      const dropZone = new Dropzone(this.$refs.dropZoneRef, {
        url: "/file/post"
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  template: `<drop-form></drop-form>`
})
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

#dropZone {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/basic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/dropzone.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-js-modal@2.0.0-rc.3/dist/index.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```